# Inheritance vs composition: How would you implement an "unordered list"? Subclass of list, or composition?

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

This came up at work and left me thinking about the best way to model this:

In Python, we have the built-in `list` container, which is a mutable sequence. Equality between two lists is defined as equality of all items in the list, in their respective positions.

Now a colleague felt the need to define a type that's a `list` for all practical purposes, except that two lists should be considered equal if they contain the same elements, in the same quantities, but in arbitrary order. Basically,

```py
unordered_list_1 = UnorderedList([1,2,3])
unordered_list_2 = UnorderedList([3,2,1])

unordered_list_1 == unordered_list_2 # True!
```

The colleague solved this by inheriting from `list` and overriding the `__eq__` special method:

```py
class UnorderedList(list):
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, UnorderedList):
      return ordered(self) == ordered(other)
    else:
      return NotImplemented
```

In this form it runs into a gotcha, because the builtin python types such as `list` take some shortcuts with their special methods; the not-equal `__ne__` special method does *not* just fall back onto the `__eq__` special method, so you get the funny scenario where two of these unordered lists can both be equal and not equal.

I suggested inheriting from `UserList` instead, which is meant to be subclassed, or maybe from one of the `collections.abc` abstract base classes. Another colleague chimed in with the familiar "Favor composition over inheritance" advice.

I feel that composition in this case would lead to *a lot* of boilerplate delegation code:

```py
class UnorderedListUsingDelegation:
  def __init__(self):
    self._list = list()

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, UnorderedListUsingDelegation):
      return ordered(self._list) == ordered(self.other._list)
    else:
      return NotImplemented

  def append(self, item):
    self._list.append(item)

  # Basically def every method implemented by class list and write delegation code for it:
  # pop, push, extend, __getitem__, __setitem__ and so on
```

So from that consideration, I feel like inheritance is exactly right here: A teeny tiny specialization of behavior.

But on the other hand: Is the `UnorderedList` actually substitutable for the `list` class? Not so sure here. If you do "normal" list operations, then you shouldn't notice whether you are using an instance of the `list` class or of the `UnorderedList` class. Inserting and retrieving of elements works just fine. On the other hand, you might get unexpected behavior when comparing lists:

```py
list1 = UnorderedList()
list2 = UnorderedList()

list1.append(1)
list2.append(3)

list1 == list2 # False

list1.append(2)
list2.append(2)

list1 == list2 # False

list1.append(3)
list2.append(1)

list1 == list2 # True!
```

I guess what I'm after is some clarity on how broadly or narrowly the Liskov substitution principle should be applied. Or maybe the solution is something altogether different. Maybe we *shouldn't* put such a "hack" into the `__eq__` special method and rather be explicit about what we're doing, by writing a function like

```py
def sorted_equal(a, b):
  return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

I assume the colleague is working with some framework that expects to be working with `list` objects but wants to inject this special way of comparing lists.

Comment: Are you sure that in the end {1,2,3} == {3,2,3}?

Comment: Been wondering if that was a typo myself.

Comment: Sorted-ness is an interesting quality; it is not just sorted vs. unsorted, but rather by what comparison function (or not sorted at all), which is difficult to encode in the type system.  There are efforts to do that, for example see here: https://kataskeue.com/gdp.pdf

Comment: Sets have equality. I was expecting this to act like a set with cardinality.

Comment: Is there any benefit in defining a new container over just providing a new comparison function that sorts its two container inputs? If one of the goal is that "so that the container with modified behavior can be used in place of the built-in List", this is a kind of Liskov situation where you can use that "hack" to cause any other pieces of software to break (to become "hacked"), if that other software assumed that a List is a List with no unexpected behavior.

Comment: One argument that can be made in favor of defining a new container is that it can have a more efficient amortized runtime: the container can maintain both a List and a Map (hashtable) internally, so that the container all-members equality comparison can be performed on the Map with O(n), and maintenance of the Map (if based on hashtable) is nearly constant O(1) per element operation.

Comment: Also, just because `List` doesn’t use `__eq__` to define `__ne__` doesn’t mean `UnorderedList` cant.

Comment: It's a [multiset](https://multiset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @rwong while that's true, the given implementation certainly doesn't have that advantage.

Comment: @candied_orange Indeed we can define `__ne__`. That whole part of the question is a bit tangential; it was the "gotcha" that the colleague encountered that caused them to post about it on our Slack channel, and from there the discussion kicked off about how it _should_ best be modeled...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Python, we have the built-in list container, which is a mutable sequence.

Your new list is not a list according to Liskov. Your list is not a sequence, it is a [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) otherwise known as a bag. Bags are equal if they contain the same elements in no specific order. There are several implementations already: google MultiSets in Python.

Don't forget about set which is built in. If your bag will only contain unique values.

Answer (score 3):

A fatal flaw of that approach is that the equals method is not "symmetric":

> For any reference values x and y, x.equals(y) must return true if and
> only if y.equals(x) return true.

Consider when you have an instance unOrderedList and another standard python orderedList.  They have the same elements but in different order.

```
unOrderedList == orderedList    // true
  but
orderedList == unOrderedList    // false
```

This will break a lot of things in hard to debug ways.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like going with a single utility method is the way to go. But it should have a name. `sorted_equal` is named for the implementation. A name like `contains_the_same_values` puts the emphasis on the true purpose of the function.